# What is the value of $P$?

Tags: probability

I have a probability problem.
$\\\\\\\\$**the problem**
A class of $100$ students, $42$ studied mathematics, $68$studied psychology, $54$ studied history, $22$ studied both mathematics and history, $25$ studied both mathematics and psychology, $7$ studied history but neither mathematics nor psychology, $10$ students studied all three subjects, $8$ didn't take any of the three. If a student is selected randomly find the probability that a person not taking psychology is taking both mathematics and history?
$\\\\\\$**My trial**
I use $$P= \frac{22}{100-68}=\frac{11}{16} $$
But the final answer is  $P=\frac{3}{8} $
. I don't know how this answer come. So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check that out of the $22$ students taking both mathematics and history, $10$ **have taken psychology also**. So answer would be $${22-10\over 100-68}={12\over 32}={3\over 8}$$